# Is there a way to set texture wrap mode as repeat in SDL 2?

Tags: textures, rendering, sdl2

In `SDL2`, I would like to render a texture on the screen, but with destination rectangle greater than texture size. Instead of stretching the texture, I would like the texture to be repeated as many time as possible.

[image]

Here is code I use (pseudo code)

```
SDL_Rect src = { x = 0, y = 0, w = texture.Width, h = texture.Height };                 
SDL_Rect dst = { x = 0, y = 0, w = texture.Width * 3, h = texture.Height * 3 };

SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, src, dst);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Sadly, this isn't something that SDL can do, which I find slightly annoying as it seems such a simple feature.

So, you'll need to implement your own loop that renders the whole texture a bunch of times and possibly crops the border textures by clamping the source rectangle.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I'm thinking about switching to another framework.

Comment: That's not necessarily a bad idea. While SDL's rendering functionality is really easy and fast to setup, it does really lack with some basic features.